# Internet Explorer 10 opens new tabs in a new window

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-10

At my university some of the computers only have internet explorer (0.0.11). The most annoying thing about this is that when you right click a link to 'open in new tab' IE then opens the link in a new window. Making research a pain to keep track of.

I have tried several google searches etc to try and solve this problem but nothing seems to work.

Has any else experienced this issue or got any advice on how to fix it? As a student I don't have admin access but something I can do to an individual PC would be awesome.

Thank you

Comment: This is handled in IE settings.  There likely a group policy that will prevent you from changing this behavior.

Comment: @Ramhound, can you advise me where this is changed in IE settings? In Internet Options > Tab Settings, I can't find anything that states what the 'open in new tab' option does. However, I do seem to be able to alter the settings there.